# Is there a way to implement something like sklearn's GridSearchCV for Tensorflow estimators?

Tags: scikit-learn, tensorflow

Grid Search CV works fine for sklearn models as well as keras, however do we have any alternative for this specifically for tf estimators? Would be great if someone can guide in right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I haven't found any examples that use TF as well as GridSearch from Sklearn.

But Tensorflow 2.0 has hparams that works like GridSearch by plotting Parallel plots with the hyperparmaeters as well as the metric for testing. A follow along example can be found here: https://medium.com/ml-book/neural-networks-hyperparameter-tuning-in-tensorflow-2-0-a7b4e2b574a1

Alternatively, For keras which is an api for TF you can use the library Ray Project (has few example files):
https://github.com/ray-project/ray or using keras-tuner 
https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner

Comment: Welcome to the site - please have a look at the guidelines here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer ; paying particular attention to the section on "Provide context for links".

Comment: Thanks! If you find my answer lacking. Please feel free to edit as I am still newbie when it comes to hyper parameter tuning  when it comes to tf.